# WebRTC remote video keeps freezing on ios Safari

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc, opentok, simplewebrtc

We have a WebRTC based solution and have been excited about WebRTC support on ios 11 Safari. However, every WebRTC solution we have tested using iPhone 6 on ios 11.0.3 experiences the same problem:

After a while the remote video freezes and the whole phone crashes requiring force reset. There seems to be no talk about such issues anywhere on Internet. Has somebody been experiencing the same and have you found any solutions?

We have replicated the issue with ios 11.0.2, ios 11.0.3, iPhone 6 iPhone 6+ and the following solutions:

- Our own WebRTC solution based on SimpleWebRTC
- Talky.io
- TokBox Safari Demo

Comment: I can confirm that this happens on my devices as well (iPhone 6 & iPad mini 2). I also found a few references on the internet: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=175014, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176439, https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/192; so far no response from Apple yet.

Comment: Also i can't get it to happen on appr.tc (this site works on ipads only); can you confirm?

Comment: It seems that this problem is fixed in 11.1

Comment: Still seeing this in 11.1, but seems fixed in the latest 11.2 beta. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Other issues on iPhone 6 devices running iOS 11 include camera freezing on the first frame captured or black screen where the video stream should be. Not sure how to fix these.

Comment: Tested in iOS 11.2 beta 4. Issues of video freezing and phone crashing as used to happen earlier has been reoslved. Lets wait for the 11.2 rollout :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been reported to webkit, see either https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=175014 or https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176439